# Is it possible to add a new option "Open Folder With X" on right click in Dolphin like there currently is "Open Folder With Kate"?

Tags: kde, plasma, dolphin

My current OS is Kde Neon, I am using Plasma with X11, it is up to date.

I noticed some applications (Gwenview for example) add extra options in the right click menu, without being associated as the default application to open folders with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems like the answer is custom service menus, thankfully KDE has [a good tutorial](https://develop.kde.org/docs/extend/dolphin/service-menus/) for writing them and it's not difficult at all.

There are a bunch actually in the Discover app under addons and even if I did end up using one from there for VS Code I'd like to post the one I wrote by hand for Sublime Text, named `openinsublime.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
MimeType=inode/directory;
Actions=openInSublime

[Desktop Action openInSublime]
Name=Open In Sublime
Icon=sublime-text.svg
Exec=subl %u
```